# How does one log all exceptions from an ASP.net MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How does one log all exceptions from an ASP.net MVC app?  Should one use logging to a text file?  If so, should this text file be saved to the computer disk or to a table in the database?

Comment: You can use an exception filter and then write the exception to a text file in there.  Might give you an idea how to get started: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling.

Comment: You can use Elmah and log exceptions to a file: https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC

Answer (score 1):

I use log4net its simple to implement
https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/

in your webconfig you add this config you can refer to https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

```
  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs\log.txt" /> <- this is where your log file will be
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

inside your controller you declare a variable to use for logging

```
readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

now anywhere inside that controller you can call this

`logger.Info("blablabla")` or `logger.Error("boom boom")` you should check documentation for more.